# Gluu customscrpit in Jython java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap$EntrySet

Tags: java, spring, maven, gluu

Hello I am new with Java, Spring, and Gluu here, so correct me If I am wrong :)

I am trying to build a jar file library to Support Custom authentication inside Gluu IDP

According to [documentation](https://gluu.org/docs/gluu-server/4.1/admin-guide/custom-script/), Gluu compiles and execute custom script using Jython - python language

I test my Jython-python using Eclipse Luna IDE, and import my jar file and it works fine

Then I built the Jar file using `maven-assembly-plugin` and this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.fns</groupId>
  <artifactId>gluu</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>gluu</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://gluubionic.local.io</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    
    <!-- Please keep (version) properties in alphabetical order! -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <gluu.version>4.1</gluu.version>
    <resteasy.version>3.0.14.Final</resteasy.version>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WebSocket Library-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- dependency 들을 모두 포함하기위한 -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.gluu.TestMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then, I tested it using windows `cmd` using `java -jar gluu-0.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar`, and it works fine too

However, After I submit it into Gluu and test it, Gluu shows me this error

```
    2021-03-23 07:00:38,904 ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [com.fns.gluu.utils.HttpUtils$1] (HttpUtils.java:120) - connectSocket handleTransportError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap$EntrySet
        at org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.entrySet(LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter.entrySet(MultiValueMapAdapter.java:160) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.entrySet(HttpHeaders.java:1738) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.AbstractMap.putAll(AbstractMap.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(TreeMap.java:327) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$StandardWebSocketClientConfigurator.beforeRequest(StandardWebSocketClient.java:201) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.JsrUpgradeListener.onHandshakeRequest(JsrUpgradeListener.java:47) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.initWebSocketHeaders(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:486) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.send(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:559) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.sendAsync(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:565) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient.connect(WebSocketClient.java:379) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connect(ClientContainer.java:242) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connectToServer(ClientContainer.java:286) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.lambda$doHandshakeInternal$0(StandardWebSocketClient.java:151) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap$EntrySet
        at org.python.core.SyspathJavaLoader.findClass(SyspathJavaLoader.java:128) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        ... 16 more
2021-03-23 07:00:38,903 ERROR [qtp1590550415-15] [com.fns.gluu.utils.HttpUtils] (HttpUtils.java:130) - WebSocketService ExecutionException.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap$EntrySet
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:134) ~[?:?]
        at com.fns.gluu.utils.HttpUtils.connectSocket(HttpUtils.java:124) ~[?:?]
        at com.fns.gluu.api.GuardianApiService.checkAuthStatus(GuardianApiService.java:82) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:190) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:208) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:477) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:481) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:141) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.pycode._pyx4.authenticate$9(gccs_test.py:105) ~[?:?]
        at org.python.pycode._pyx4.call_function(gccs_test.py) ~[?:?]
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:173) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:306) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:197) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:485) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:237) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:228) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:218) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:213) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyObject._jcallexc(PyObject.java:3565) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.core.PyObject._jcall(PyObject.java:3598) ~[jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.python.proxies.__main__$PersonAuthentication$4.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.gluu.oxauth.service.external.ExternalAuthenticationService.executeExternalAuthenticate(ExternalAuthenticationService.java:196) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.gluu.oxauth.service.external.ExternalAuthenticationService$Proxy$_$_WeldClientProxy.executeExternalAuthenticate(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.gluu.oxauth.auth.Authenticator.userAuthenticationInteractive(Authenticator.java:321) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.gluu.oxauth.auth.Authenticator.authenticateImpl(Authenticator.java:204) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.gluu.oxauth.auth.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:132) ~[classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247) ~[org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267) ~[org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
        at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) ~[weld-web-3.1.2.Final.jar:3.1.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) ~[weld-web-3.1.2.Final.jar:3.1.2.Final]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:330) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1395) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:226) ~[websocket-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.gluu.oxauth.audit.debug.ServletLoggingFilter.doFilter(ServletLoggingFilter.java:67) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590) ~[jetty-security-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383) ~[jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547) [jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375) [jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270) [jetty-server-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) [jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) [jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap$EntrySet
        at org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.entrySet(LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter.entrySet(MultiValueMapAdapter.java:160) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.entrySet(HttpHeaders.java:1738) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.AbstractMap.putAll(AbstractMap.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(TreeMap.java:327) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$StandardWebSocketClientConfigurator.beforeRequest(StandardWebSocketClient.java:201) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.JsrUpgradeListener.onHandshakeRequest(JsrUpgradeListener.java:47) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.initWebSocketHeaders(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:486) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.send(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:559) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.sendAsync(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:565) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient.connect(WebSocketClient.java:379) ~[websocket-client-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connect(ClientContainer.java:242) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connectToServer(ClientContainer.java:286) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.lambda$doHandshakeInternal$0(StandardWebSocketClient.java:151) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        ... 1 more
```

I was confused, because `org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap$EntrySet` is already inside the jar file.

According to my code, It is caused because I want to make a Stomp connection using `WebSocketStompClient.connect` function from `org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient`

Am I missing some steps here?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear to me, but I think you want to use gluu's custom script feature. You can check some examples [here](https://github.com/GluuFederation/oxAuth/tree/master/Server/integrations), you don't need to build a jar for it, you can control every step using gluu's built in custom scripts.

Comment: Actually, I also tried some of them which I think it is related to my problem. However, I solved it by making a full Jython code without including (or calling) any jar file. Thank you @ChristianH

Comment: This is a known issue in 4.1, Gluu fixed it in 4.2